# Scala Random Number

Tags: scala, random, lower-bound

Ok, I understand how to implement a random number generator in Scala and how to set the upper bound for the random number being generated, but I am confused as how to change the lower bound.
For example:

```
    var computerGuess= scala.util.Random
    var higher=100
    var computerGuessInt=computerGuess.nextInt(higher)
```

will let the computer generate a random number from 0 to 100.

But I want to change the lower bound to be, say 29 so that the computer could pick a random number from 29 to 100. How can I do this?

Comment: Not to nitpick on your code but have you looked at functional programming as a programming methodology and why using vals instead of vars will be beneficial in many cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without getting into language specific solutions (scala may have an API for generating a number with a lower bound) - you could always create your own lower bound by *adding it to the number generated*.

This means that to generate a number from 29 to 100, you can generate a number from 0 to 71, and add 29 to it:

```
var computerGuess = scala.util.Random
var higher = 100
var lower = 29
var computerGuessInt = computerGuess.nextInt(higher - lower) + lower
```

Comment: Please use `val` whenever possible.